# What are the commas in my /etc/passwd file?

Tags: linux, unix, etcpasswd

There are weird commas after the real-name parameter of some lines in my `/etc/passwd` file.

> kye:x:1000:100:Kye,,,:/home/kye:/bin/bash

What gives?  Why are they there?  Can I remove them?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Some tool you used to create the account (adduser?) added them. The tool in question sees the comment / real name field in the passwd file as a GECOS field:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gecos_field

The field values are

1. User's full name (or application name, if the account is for a
   program)
2. Building and room number or contact person
3. Office telephone number
4. Any other contact information (pager number, fax, etc.)

However, I cannot think of an applicaton which uses them. I believe these fields are close to useless. Use a different tool for adding users (useradd?) or explicitely give a value for the GECOS field if possible.

Comment: Real name is very widely used. The other fields used to be displayed by the `finger` tool ([example](http://nullroute.eu.org/finger/?q=mjbauer@athena.dialup.mit.edu)).

Comment: Actually, subfield #4 is "Home telephone number".  "Other" is subfields #5 and onwards.  And to expand upon `grawity`'s point: Taking the commas out doesn't change the tools that use the field (`finger`, many MTSes, and so on).  Those programs will still stop reading the full name at the first comma, semi-colon, or percent sign that they encounter.  Explicit commas, even if the subfields that they delimit are all empty, are a useful reminder of this.